# Camera preview not working in full screen in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, camera, preview

I have added a camera/video function to my app, but the preview is not matching the screen size. I tried few solutions, but in most of the cases it's not changing anything or the ratio is off.

Below is the code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: const Icon(UniconsLine.multiply,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 30));
          })),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return Transform.scale(
              scale: 1 /
                  (_cameraController!.value.aspectRatio *
                      mediaSize.aspectRatio),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!),
            );
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _cameraController?.takePicture();

            if (!mounted) return;

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image!.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: (widget.isVideo)
            ? const Icon(UniconsLine.video)
            : const Icon(UniconsLine.camera),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
```

Any idea ?
Thanks